# GCC. Generate limited debug info

Tags: gcc, dwarf, objcopy, addr2line

Is there a way to force `gcc` to generate only subset of full debug info that will be sufficient for `addr2line` utility? Or any way to strip unneeded? I've tried

> $ objcopy --only-keep-debug --remove-section=.debug_loc --remove-section=.debug_aranges --remove-section=.debug_frame my-elf-file

Is there anything that may be stripped in addition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `-g1`.  This produces minimal debug info for backtraces.  From the manual:

> Level 1 produces minimal information, enough for making backtraces in
>   parts of the program that you don't plan to debug.  This includes
>   descriptions of functions and external variables, and line number
>   tables, but no information about local variables.

You can also strip some of the debug info after the fact.  One way to do this is described in [the gdb "MiniDebugInfo" documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/MiniDebugInfo.html).

Comment: Seems like `addr2line` doesn't understand `.gnu_debugdata`, but `-g1` should be enough for me.